# Will hydrogen chloride dissolved in ethanol react with magnesium?

Tags: acid-base, reaction-mechanism, redox, solutions

Magnesium will react with aqueous HCl to form magnesium chloride and hydrogen gas. Simple. But I've just read in my textbook that HCl in a solution of ethanol no reaction will take place. There is no explanation given.

I know HCl is soluble in both solutions, but I cannot figure out what accounts for the difference in reactivity with Mg. I suppose it must be due to waters ability to act as a Bronsted-Lowry base and form a hydronium ion, but I also can't see how this would be an effective intermediate in the reaction mechanism.
I am lost, and would appreciate any expertise in this area.

Comment: I find the textbook's claim to be highly suspicious.

Comment: I agree. Which textbook is this?

Comment: The textbook is Hodder IB Higher Level Chemistry